# Richtexteditor font and color change in code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I downloaded the `richtexteditor` and linked in my project.

```
RTE:Editor ID="txtResortInfo" runat="server"   Height="335px" Width="1001px"
```

Any content or any font, user entered into editor and clicked save button. 
I'd like to change font and size in code behind.

Comment: Which richtext editor you are using in you code?

Comment: RichTextEditor.dll.  http://richtexteditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Changing CSS in RTE]

Above image shows the property for changing the css on codebehind.